# input autocomplete background color

Tags: css, html, autocomplete

I have been looking online for days for a way to change the background color for the input box autocomplete drop down list that shows up when you begin typing. Right now I get a drop down list with a gray background and text that is slightly smaller than the input box text.

I want to change the background to white and increase the text size to be the same size as the text in the input box. Here is the code:

```
input {
     width: 485px;
     border: 1px solid rgb(150,150,150);
     background: white;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 10px;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-size: 1em;
}


<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search"> 
            <input id="searchBox" type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" value="" autofocus/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to style the dropdown since it is not part of the DOM, your only option would be to make your own dropdown to be able to style it.

Comment: How do you create an auto complete drop down list that functions the same as the input box autocomplete drop down list? Also, how would I override the built in autocomplete box that is not part of the DOM?